# Может ли клиент подождать ответа от сервера?

Tags: gwt, java, клиент-сервер

Изучаю GWT. Клиент шлет запрос серверу. При получении ответа браузер вызывает асинхронный метод клиента. Все работает.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы клиент **ждал** ответа от сервера ? Мои эксперименты показали, что:

1) `notify()` на стороне клиента не реализован (компилится, но выдает ошибку при загрузке модуля);

2) циклический код с `sleep()` не прерывается (асинхронный `callback` не вызывается, пока этот цикл работает), хотя сервер ответ давно отослал. (Это наверное объясняет, почему не реализовали `notify()`).

Какие есть соображения по поводу реализации поведения с ожиданием ответа ?

**UPD**
К ответу (и комментариям) @nofate. Пишу в дополнениях, потому что комментарии пропадают.

Будьте любезны, объясните новичку в веб-программировании, что такое **div**. Неоднократно встречал его в вопросах-ответах, а спросить, что это такое не решался.

На предмет `threads` у клиента я понял, что их там нет. Т.е. остается только игра с графическим интерфейсом.

Или, все-таки, есть средства вмешаться в обработку очереди событий данного окна ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Природа xmlhttprequest такова, что он изначально работает асинхронно. Или вы хотите, чтобы браузер зависал на время выполнения запроса?

Если же вам просто требуется ограничить активность пользователя на время ожидания ответа, то можно выводить на этот период div со стилем `position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;`

---

**UPD1.** Под дивом подразумевают элемент страницы, соответствующий HTML-тегу `<div>`. Вам, наверное, стоит что-нибудь почитать о способах верстки и HTML вообще. Можете воспринимать его просто как элемент-контейнер внутри страницы. Ну, что-то вроде окна из терминологии WinAPI (у вас судя по постам достаточно опыта в c/c++ ).

В очередь обработки событий окна браузера вас, конечно, никто не пустит. Просто у вас есть html-страница описывающая структуру документа (DOM) и  js-сценарий(ии) описывающие некоторое поведение. Браузер пробегается по дереву DOM, отрисовывает элементы разметки и выполняет код из <script>-тегов. Кроме того к элементам DOM могут быть назначены обработчики событий (например onClick), которым можно назначить фрагмент скрипта. Чаще всего назначается вызов  функции, объявленной ранее. Этих строительных кирпичиков достаточно, чтобы сооружать такие навороченные вещи, как ExtGWT или, например, полноценный [эмулятор Linux на i386](http://bellard.org/jslinux/).

Вы упоминали про создание игр, для этой цели возможно стоит обратить внимание не на GWT, а на средства HTML5 и, в частности, тег Canvas.

Надеюсь, мои рассуждения чем-то помогут. Если где-то соврал, пусть более опытные в js товарищи поправят (я осведомлен все же больше по Java, чем по JavaScript).

Comment: Совершенно не понял, что выводить, как это будет выглядеть, какие методы GWT (SmartGWT) для этого надо вызывать. 

Я понял так, что callback отработает. Каковы должны быть его действия для возобновления активности пользователя ?

На самом деле просто не хочется в куче мест интерфейса проверять готовность данных от сервера и выводить окошко с надписью "**in progress...**".

Насчет браузер  зависал - нет. Кстати, не в курсе, а threads запускать внутри браузера можно ? Но идеальным был бы вариант обработки прерываний с приоритетами и маскированием.

Но ... мечтать не вредно (это я себе).

Comment: Можно, например, написать обертку для AsyncCallback<T>, которая при старте запроса будут рисовать на экран большой полупрозрачный виджет с анимацией загрузки, а при приходе результата скрывать его.

Многопоточности в javascript нет, но ее можно эмулировать при помощи отложенных заданий (http://javascript.ru/blog/tenshi/mnogopotochnyi-yavaskript).

Comment: А объясните в двух словах, для новичка в мире web-программирования, что такое **div**. Неоднократно встречал в вопросах-ответах, но спросить не решался.

Comment: Спасибо ! Вопрос пока не закрываю, может еще что-нибудь ценное узнаю.